# What does "number represented by the 5-tuple" mean?

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map

As in from homework problem:

> Plot this function in K-map:
>
> \$F(A,B,C,D,E)\$ is 1 if the number represented by the 5-tuple (A,B,C,D,E)
>   is even or divisible by 3.

Does this mean I should treat each word as a binary number? For example:

\$F(0,1,1,0,0) = 1\$ because 01100 is even number.

\$F(0,1,0,0,1)= 1\$  because 01001 is 9 in decimal and 9 is divisible by 3.

Comment: I think there's more information needed to answer this. Is there any context about how to construct a number from A, B, C, D, and E? I don't feel like it's a given that each letter represents a binary bit.

Comment: I take that back... if this is a Karnaugh Map, then they probably are binary bits.

Comment: That's all it says on the problem.  Nothing in the textbook explains anything about tuples.  I tried to look around the internet and I couldn't find anything either. And yes, they are binary bits.

Comment: Based on this wikipedia example, I suspect your approach is correct:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map#Example

Comment: I believe that your approach is right - this is what I've done in the past for divisibility problems with k-maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Tuple"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) is math-speak for an ordered array of elements. "Number represented by the ...-tuple" in the context of boolean variables does in fact refer to a binary number whose bit positions match the variables within the tuple, with the rightmost element being the LSb and the leftmost being the MSb.